# pattern to avoid (or delegate?) NPE

Tags: java, scala

In code reviews I stumbled over this java-pattern to avoid NPE's:

```
value = (null != someObject) ? someObject.someOtherMethod() : null
```

I doubt that this is "good style". I rather think that it delegates the NPE (BTW this sounds similar to mapping over a Scala-Option-value or a Haskell-Maybe... )

Is it good style or not? If not, how to improve ?

**Edit:** Supposing it scatters your code, the code will get unreadable:
**Is this already encapsulated in some libraries / API ?** (apache-commons, google-coomons or similar !?)

Comment: Style value judgement questions are off-topic for StackOverflow. You might try http://programmers.stackexchange.com but I don't know if it's their sort of thing either.

Comment: `how to improve` - Well, as far as just this line of code is concerned, there is nothing to improve, until we know where you would be using your `value`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. May be [codereview.se] is the place.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid piece of code and exactly what one needs in certain contexts. It defers an NPE only if it is used in a wrong place.

Comment: removed the styling tag. but I still wonder, if this is in any libraries ...

Comment: In scala, you'd use `val value = Option(someObject).map(_.someOtherMethod)` and that's all really basic behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained) will help you.

Also see [similar qustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java).

Comment: Great stuff! Also great explanation. Thanks for that one, saved my day :-)

Answer (score 3):

This pattern is neither good or not good.  You'd need to evaluate it in context.

The key question is why `someObject` can have `null` values, and whether it is meaningful ... or a bug.

- On the one hand, `null` might have a specific meaning (e.g. something like "the value is unspecified"), and the code might be dealing with that in a legitimate way.
- On the other hand, `null` might be a symptom of a bug (e.g. someone forgot to initialize something).  In that case, the code is spreading the damage and / or making the source of the bug harder to find ... and therefore bad.

---

As a general observation, a lot of code / coders take the view that the best way to avoid unexpected NPEs is to liberally scatter stuff like this throughout the code-base as a preventative measure.  In fact, this is exactly the wrong thing to do.  The right approach is to let the NPE happen (or better still, force it to happen -- see @vacuum's Answer), figure out where the unexpected `null` is coming from ... and remove the source.  And (of course!) you need to test extensively so that the unexpected nulls get picked up before you go into production.

IMO, it is best practice to treat a `null` as an error *unless* it has a well defined and documented meaning.

Comment: yes. very good indeed. that's a lesson for me.

Answer (score 1):

If the `null` can eventually be handled gracefully but cannot be handled there, then it's a perfectly reasonable pattern.

If the `null` assuredly can't be handled gracefully, then it's counterproductive.  Better to fail fast.

Answer (score 0):

This idiom is impossible to encapsulate in an API. It would need first-class language support (or the language would need to support macros), especially if you want to generalize to arbitrarily many steps in the return-derefence-return chain.

I like to avoid littering code with these kinds of checks so in some projects I found myself using a piece of reflection code that accepts a string, which it interprets as a chain of method calls, and does the right thing. Type-unsafe, of course, but many times that is not a major concern.

Comment: First-class language support sounds comfortable.